# How to make javascript flow wait till an element is completely rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, sapui5

```
 test.view.js

        timeDBox = new sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox({layoutData: new sap.ui.layout.GridData({linebreak: true}),
             change: function(oEvent){
              oController.getKeyEqChart();
             },
            }),

          new sap.ui.core.HTML({
                content: "<div id=\"chart1\"></div>",
                afterRendering: function(e){
                 console.log("chart1 create"+timeDBox.getValue());
                 chart1DivReady = true;
                 oController.getchart();

                }
            })       
          test.controller.js             
          onInit: function() {
      var modelDataEvent = {"genericTableModel":[{"xtime":"1"},{"xtime":"2"},{"xtime":"3"},{"xtime":"4"},{"xtime":"5"},{"xtime":"8"},{"xtime":"10"}]}
      var oTemplate11 = new sap.ui.core.ListItem({text : "{xtime}", key : "{xtime}"});
      timeDBox.setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(modelDataEvent));
      timeDBox.bindItems("/genericTableModel", oTemplate11);
      timeDBox.getModel().refresh();          
      this.getchart();
        },            
        getchart: function(){            
        var jsonObjToSend = {} ;
      jsonObjToSend["dialogue"] = "terminal";
      jsonObjToSend["cid"] = "key_equipment ";
      var srachmap = {} ;
      srachmap["xtime"] =  timeDBox.getValue();
      jsonObjToSend["search"] =  srachmap; this.doAjax("/uri/uri",jsonObjToSend).done(this.updateKeyEqChart);        
        },
    updateKeyEqChart: function(modelData) {    
  var svg = d3.select("#chart1").append("svg")
   1) if i call getchart method from onInit, chart1 id is not created when executing this method
  2) if i call getchart chart from oController.getchart() at that time timeDBox.getValue() value is not created which is required to get chart data
 },
```

I am using a drop down list in my application which is populated from database.

Following things happen after the drop down gets populated:

1. Once the drop down gets populated I use the value of the drop down to render a chart by doing another ajax call to the db.
2. If the drop down is not populated by the time the flow reaches there then later the chart is not rendered but with time the drop down gets rendered as the ajax where I send param from drop down is null as the drop down is not ready.
3. So how to make the control wait till the drop down is populated and then go the chart call.

Comment: blah blah blah blah... Make your post readable please?

Comment: Just a guess based on an event handler name, put your chart call in the afterRendering handler.

Comment: afterRendering is userbuilt function written by me. When i call getchart chart from oController.getchart() at that time timeDBox.getValue() value is not created which is required to get chart data which is why it is failing.
 afterRendering: function(e){
                 console.log("chart1 create"+timeDBox.getValue());
                 chart1DivReady = true;
                 oController.getchart();

while doing above:
srachmap["xtime"] =  timeDBox.getValue();
The drop box above is not rendered at the time I am getting the data which is why it is failing.

Comment: @user3069962 If i understand what you said, return from getchart() promise object (`return this.doAjax(...).done(...)`) and you should then set your logic in callback using `oController.getchart().done(callback);`. NOW read your question again, do you really thing it is clear?

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure that I understand your questions right and the code sample being almost unreadable doesn't help.

But I think onInit might not be the lifecycle hook you are looking for.

If it is a one time deal, I would use **onAfterRendering**:

```
onAfterRendering: function() {
// Code
}
```

If this has to be executed everytime you navigate to this page, then I would add **onAfterShow/onBeforeShow** delegates in the onInit function.

```
onInit: function () {

        view.addEventDelegate({

/**
 * use either or in your case
 */
            onAfterShow: function (oEvt) {
                // If you use a busy dialog, you want to close it here
            },

            onBeforeShow: function (oEvt) {

            }

        });
    },
```

Hope this helps.